# List Category posts Wordpress plugin not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress and trying to use the List Category WordPress plugin to show posts by category on the home page. I have installed and activated the plugin and as given in their documentation (https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts/blob/master/readme.txt), added the following code to the `index.php` file to get posts by category name:

`[catlist name="bike-rides"]`
(it is surrounded by ` on both sides, stackoverflow is formatting it)

On adding this code, this text shows up on the website instead of showing posts by this category.[image]

Can anyone please help? I am probably doing something very stupid so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi can you please try this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[catlist name="bike-rides"]' ); ?>
```

we should use `do_shortcode` function to insert shortcodes inside php files in wordpress, pls try it